# Displaying something on line chart when only one bar selected in range bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

When i select a single bar in the range chart below i need to represent it somehow in the linechart above it, currently the line chart shows nothing... any ideas?

[chart.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhliQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask great questions. Provide more details, your code, a working fiddle.

Comment: Although I agree with @iulian that more detail would be helpful (or even better, a fiddle demonstrating the problem), I would venture to guess that this is https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/949. Please see if 2.0 fixes this, will be released soon!